# Rails not found in specific rails project folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've installed rails using rvm. I've loaded rvm using ~/.bahsrc.

rails is working fine.

```
which rails
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rails
```

but in that rails project folder which command says

```
/home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@something/bin/rails
```

How's this happening? How to make my rails work in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the root of a rails project you may use

`./script/rails --version # (or whatever rails command you want to call)`

to be sure to use the rails version that corresponds to your project. Usually rails magic will apply inside a rails project and "happen" to find the correct version of rails, but there seems to be a number of things that can go wrong about that.